# I have list of videos I want to play only one video in popup modal

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have list of videos and I want videos to play only when I click the thumbnail.

```
<video style="min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; " id="vid" width="auto" height="auto" controls autoplay="true" loop="loop" preload="auto" muted="muted">
<source src="video/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video/sample.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="divVideo">
<video id="MyVideo" style="min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; " id="vid" width="auto" height="auto" controls autoplay="true" loop="loop" preload="auto" muted="muted">
    <source src="video/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Then write a javascript function to load different videos

```
function changeVideo(source){
  var $video=$("#MyVideo")[0];
  $("#MyVideo source").attr('src', source);
  $video.load();
  $video.play();
}
```

suppose you have 3 thumbnails as

```
<img class="thumbnail" data-url="source1" src="img1"/>
<img class="thumbnail" data-url="source2" src="img2"/>
<img class="thumbnail" data-url="source3" src="img3"/>
```

in document ready,
write function

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function(){
changeVideo($(this).attr("data-url"));
});
```

FOr showing in a modal pop up just make use of bootstrap modal pop up
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

in that to load video into the pop up use

```
$(".modal-body").html($("#divVideo").html());
```

after this write the command to show pop up

```
$("#MyModal").show()
```